# How do I get a HP LaserJet 5N printer working?

Tags: printing

How can I use an old (but in working condition) HP LaserJet 5N printer in Ubuntu OS when I no longer have the software and can't locate a driver to download?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try just adding the printer in Ubuntu; the Add Printer wizard may be able to find a driver for you.

Answer (score 1):

HP printers have very good support in Linux thanks to HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP).

Just connect the printer and go to System → Administration → Printing a try to add this printer and Ubuntu will try to find a driver for your printer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this printer should work with the LaserJet 5 printer driver which is available when you Add your printer in the Printers window.